# Program acts likes waiting for a character

Tags: c, fork

I have this code:

```
#include <sys/types.h> /* pid_t */
#include <sys/wait.h>  /* waitpid */
#include <stdio.h>     /* printf, perror */
#include <stdlib.h>    /* exit */
#include <unistd.h>    /* _exit, fork */
#include <string.h>

void rec(n)
{
  int l, r;
  char *new_args[] = {"./bla1", NULL };
  if (n)
  {
    l = fork();
    if (l!=0)   //parent
        r = fork();
    if (l == 0 || r == 0) 
    {
     rec(--n); //return;
    }   
/*  if (l == 0) {
        rec(--n); return; }
    r = fork();
    if (r == 0) {
        rec(--n);  }*/
  }
  else //call Sorters
  {
    printf("Execv!!!!\n"); 
//  if (execv(new_args[0], &new_args[0]) < 0) perror("execvp error!\n");
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {
  rec(3);
  return 0; 
}
```

and i get these results:

> vasilis@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ Execv!!!!
>   Execv!!!!
>   Execv!!!!
>   Execv!!!!
>   Execv!!!!
>   Execv!!!!
>   Execv!!!!
>                     **<---- HERE is empty and it was like it was waiting for a char**
>   vasilis@ubuntu:~/Desktop$

At the point that I am showing it was like it was waiting for a character. I pressed Enter and then the program terminated. Any ideas why?

Comment: It's not waiting for any input; it's just that the output has made the prompt disappear!

Comment: what does repeating the `!` four times mean? You know what they say about people who write things like `!!`, `!!!` and so on?

Comment: @glglgl yes. They are called chess reporters :-). !! means a very good  move in chess.  And other sport reporters, too. The number of exclamation marks indicates the strength of the shouting.

Answer (score 0):

Simply your 8 leaf children all want to write a string to the console. And they are doing it simultaneously. As a result, their symbols, including \n, are mixed. More of it, the main task returns and the shell writes the vasilis@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ to the same console, too. It is very strange that you are seeing SOMETHING sensible at all.

They should put their output to some queue, prettily one after another, and to do the output only when all work is done.

Comment: What you call "The main thread" (here we have no threads!) returns indeed. But as it isn't here any longer, it doesn't write a prompt. That is done by the calling shell.

Comment: @glglgl  Yes, of course. Thank you for pointing at my mistakes. And do you know why he is not getting absolute garbage?

Comment: As written in my answer: the output is done in one `write()` call. That is probably exactly the reason why it is done in one "shot".

Comment: It is done in 8 copies of write(). The file id is the same. So, it can be done anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your children writes the said string to the console.

As it does so in one `write()` call, the output remains intact.

But: while your child processes do that "in background", the parent process silently exits and returns to the prompt, which you see in the very first line.

As the childs's outputs are printed *after* the prompt was already given, it is (of course) not repeated. If you enter `ls` instead of just pressing enter, you'll see that.